# Where does the 'C' in exhaled CO₂ mostly come from?

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, cellular-respiration

When a human being exhales CO₂, what is, by the numbers, the main source of carbon atoms exiting the body in this way? I mean what class of cells, or which tissues are the biggest on a pie chart of where carbon atoms breathed out in the form of CO₂ molecules came from?

Comment: Duh, I just realized it's probably mostly from leftovers after the sugars that you eat are burned for energy. I've also heard that broken-down fat from weight-losers gets breathed out. Is that at all true?

Comment: yes, the CO2 is the product of various metabolic processes. I can expand if you want...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

CO<sub>2</sub> is a product of [Cellular Respiration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellular_respiration), which generally takes Glucose and molecular Oxygen to produce Carbon Dioxide, water, heat, and allows ADP to be regenerated into ATP (or other various oxidation reactions). The **Carbon** comes from wherever the acetyl-CoA used in the Citric Acid Cycle came from - either carboyhydrates or fatty-acids (saturated carbon chains).

```
Simplified reaction:   C6H12O6 (s) + 6 O2 (g) → 6 CO2 (g) + 6 H2O (l) + heat
```

So, you are correct. CO<sub>2</sub> transferring out of the lungs is mostly the result of burning sugars (or fats) for energy (the regeneration of ADP/GDP with respect to human biology).

To that end, the tissues that produce the most CO<sub>2</sub> will be the cell-types which constantly require energy. Nominally, *muscle tissues*.

Per your comment, broken down fat, or rather, the process of [Fatty-Acid Catabolism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatty_acid_metabolism), results in the production of **acetyl-CoA**, which is a primary player in the [Citric-Acid Cycle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citric_acid_cycle). The Citric Acid Cycle, which you should recognize as the Cycle that **Pyruvate** - the end result of [Glycolysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycolysis) (the breakdown of Glucose into 2x 3-Carbon Pyruvates) - also goes into after being converted into **acetyl-CoA** by Pyruvate Dehydrogenase.

```
The sum of all reactions in the citric acid cycle is:
Acetyl-CoA + 3 NAD+ + Q + GDP + Pi + 2 H2O → CoA-SH + 3 NADH + 3 H+ + QH2 + GTP + 2 CO2
```

So, for a basic breakdown with respect to CO2:

- Carbohydrates (Sugars, Starches) **→** Glucose **→ Pyruvate** + ATP + NADH
- **Pyruvate → *Acetyl-CoA***
- Lipids (fats) **→** Lipolysis **→ *Acetyl-CoA***
- **Acetyl-CoA** + ... + H<sub>2</sub>0 **→** ... + **CO<sub>2</sub>**

Comment: In the resting state it's the brain that is responsible for the largest proportion of cellular respiration: estimates vary but are usually in the 20-25% range. This is because even at rest the nervous system is working hard to maintain the ion gradients that are essential for propagation of action potentials.

Answer (score 8):

**At rest, the main sources of CO<sub>2</sub> are the brain, liver and heart.**

The original questions seems to me to be asking for information about which tissues or organs are responsible for producing most of the exhaled CO<sub>2</sub>. As other answers have mentioned, CO<sub>2</sub> production by cells reflects the amount of oxidative metabolism that is being carried out. This means that we can answer the question by simply asking - which tissues/organs are responsible for consuming the most O<sub>2</sub>?

There are many sources of information about this, but the most succinct statement that I have found is [here](http://science.jrank.org/pages/856/Biochemical-Oxygen-Demand.html):

> The average human body of 139 lb (63 kg) consumes 250 ml of O<sub>2</sub> each minute. The major single-organ oxygen consumers are the liver, brain, and heart (consuming 20.4%, 18.4%, and 11.6%, respectively), while the sum total of all the body's skeletal muscles consume about 20%. In addition, the kidneys use up about 7.2%, and the skin uses 4.8%. The rest of the body consumes the remaining 17.6% of the oxygen. Oxygen use can also be measured per 100 gm of an organ to indicate concentrations of use; as such, heart usage is highest, followed by the kidneys, then the brain, and then the liver. During exercise, the biochemical oxygen demand increases for active tissues including the heart and skeletal muscles.

Other sources are in broad agreement with this. Note however that these are values at rest. As the quotation states, during active exercise the skeletal muscle will become the major source of CO<sub>2</sub>.

Answer (score 3):

The chemical formula for glucose is C<sub>6</sub>H<sub>12</sub>O<sub>6</sub>. When the body needs energy, the glucose molecule is broken down to give CO<sub>2</sub> and water:

$C_6H_{12}O_6 + 6O_2 => 6CO_2 + 6H_2O$

Therefore, I think "C" comes mostly from glucose molecules.

Answer (score 1):

The two main chemical processes in the human body that generate carbon dioxide (CO<sub>2</sub>) are:

1. Basal metabolic process of CO<sub>2</sub> (CO<sub>2m</sub>) produced by the **combustion of sugar** in organs and tissues of the body.
2. **Bacterial decay** processes occurring as a result of activity of the microbial fauna in the colon. This forms CO<sub>2</sub> (CO<sub>2c</sub>), H<sub>2</sub>, CH<sub>4</sub> and higher hydrocarbons, NH<sub>3</sub>, H<sub>2</sub>S and other mercaptans.

The total level of carbon dioxide in the blood (CO<sub>2b</sub>) is therefore the sum of the metabolic (CO<sub>2m</sub>) and carbon dioxide arising in the large bowel (CO<sub>2c</sub>). In certain circumstances CO<sub>2c</sub> arising in the colon may be resorb into the bloodstream.

Comment: Could you add a citation or two to provide readers of your answers the chance to do further reading? It is considered a prerequisite for valid answers at Biology.SE to include references.  I type-edited your answer a bit. Welcome to Bio.SE and thanks for your contribution! +1